# Bloomberg API in Java

Tags: java, vba, bloomberg

I am trying to translate from bloomberg excel vba to bloomberg java api.

For example, how to translate this sentence?
*=BDH("IBM US Equity","LAST_PRICE",Hourly_Start,Hourly_End,"BarTp=T","BarSz=60","Dir=V","Dts=S","Sort=D","Points=20")*

I am not especially not sure about the Hourly_Start part, can I do this? 
*request.set("startDate","Hourly_Start");*
Also, how to set the BarTp=T Dir=V part?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is `Hourly_Start`? Is it a named range?

Comment: This function is supposed to see the last price within the last hour.I know the interval can be set to 60 min, but I am not really sure how to set the start and end date.

Comment: I understand but `Hourly_Start` is not a valid syntax in Excel as is - it is most likely a named range and that range contains a value. Got to the "DATA" tab, click on "Name Manager" and find the named range in the list. You can then go to that cell to find its value.

Comment: Yes, you are right! By the way, can I just ask is it possible to get intraday bar value for more than one securities in one java file or do I need to create different sessions? Thanks!

Comment: IIRC you can only have one ticker per intraday bar request, but you can submit multiple requests concurrently to the same session, no need to create a new one per request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Probably will ask more questions as I try:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some experience requesting historical prices using bloomberg C# api. 
you can do `request.getElement("startDate").SetValue(startdate)`

startdate you pass in is a string representation of the DateTime in a specific format. I would start with downloading java api examples and look at an example related to historical prices

for the other parameters in the excel example trick is to figure out the mapping of the request element to the parmeter passed.